# Triple (same) event in GTM debugger

Tags: google-tag-manager

Has anyone encountered a problem when in event preview mode GTM event is sent 3 times. http://prntscr.com/r3okdq

Guide and code in article: https://dcarlbom.com/google-tag-manager/event-tracking-gtm-when-visitor-copies-text-from-page/

Data Layer info - same, only gtm.uniqueEventId is different

Thanks

Comment: I am not encountering any problems with the script. Could you provide a url where you have implemented this on? @Mr.Robot

Comment: GTM might behave differently in preview mode (as variables get evaluated every time they are used, live evaluates only once per event), so you should check if this happens in the live version, too.